# how to get all the positions of the set bits of a binary string in java?

Tags: java, string, binary

For example if the binary string is 10100010 then the program must return 1st,3rd and 7th i.e the positions of the 1's.

Comment: In case you are wondering about the downvotes: the purpose of this site is not to ask other people to do your homework. You shouldnt ask "please do it for me", but "this is what I have done so far; and here I am stuck".

Comment: @Sourav Deb atleast consider my answer and check it as correct if it helped you .!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the code which you are looking for note that regex starts with zeroth position.

```
String regex = "[1]"; 
String data = "10100010"; 
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(data);
while(m.find())
{
System.out.println(m.group() + "  => " + (m.start()+1) );
}
```

Comment: It very much looks like this question boils down to "please do my homework for me". And you just did that. Meaning: as tempting as it is to answer such no-brainer questions; most likely you are **not** doing the person asking a real favor. Because he would learn **much** from doing it on his own. (all imho)

Comment: Well, seems that didnt work out. And btw: your answer is overly complex. Do you really think a newbie needs to use regular expressions?

Comment: @EddyG you dont need to worry about it he will in future or now require to use regex and this some thing that even OCJP also explains to use whenever you have to fetch the data from the String so chill out for a perfect solution which provided above

Comment: @Sourav Deb kindly upvote it if it helped you atleast consider it as a helpful response

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Convert it to an integer/long (if possible) and then shift one bit each time and check if it's 1. For example:

   ```
   String str = "10100010";
   Integer x = Integer.valueOf(str);
   int len = str.length();
   while (x != 0) {
       if (x & 0x1 == 1) {
           System.out.println(len);
       }
       len--;
       x >>= 1;
   }
   ```
2. Scan the string by-index and check if its' value is 1:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
       if (str.chatAt(i) == '1') {
           //print
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
 char[] str="10100010".toCharArray();
        for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
            if(str[i]=='1'){
                int setBit=1;
                setBit+=i;
                System.out.println(setBit+"th");
            }
        }
```